# Parallel processing and temporary files

Tags: r, random, parallel-processing, multicore

I'm using the `mclapply` function in the `multicore` package to do parallel processing. It seems that all child processes started produce the same names for temporary files given by the `tempfile` function. i.e. if I have four processors,

```
library(multicore)
mclapply(1:4, function(x) tempfile())
```

will give four exactly same filenames. Obviously I need the temporary files to be different so that the child processes don't overwrite each others' files. When using `tempfile` indirectly, i.e. calling some function that calls `tempfile` I have no control over the filename.

Is there a way around this? Do other parallel processing packages for R (e.g. `foreach`) have the same problem?

**Update**: This is no longer an issue since R 2.14.1.

```
CHANGES IN R VERSION 2.14.0 patched:

[...]

o tempfile() on a Unix-alike now takes the process ID into account.
  This is needed with multicore (and as part of parallel) because
  the parent and all the children share a session temporary
  directory, and they can share the C random number stream used to
  produce the uniaue part.  Further, two children can call
  tempfile() simultaneously.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least for now, I chose to monkey-patch my way around this by using the following code in my `.Rprofile` following Daniel's advice to use PID values.

```
assignInNamespace("tempfile.orig", tempfile, ns="base")
.tempfile = function(pattern="file", tmpdir=tempdir())
    tempfile.orig(paste(pattern, Sys.getpid(), sep=""), tmpdir)
assignInNamespace("tempfile", .tempfile, ns="base")
```

Obviously it's not a good option for any package you'd distribute, but for a single user's need it's the best option thus far since it works in all cases.

Comment: If daniel provided you with the answer, shouldn't he get the green tickmark? What do other people think?

Comment: One was of reconciling would be to include this answer as an edit to the original Q and award the solved check to Daniel. My two cents.

Answer (score 7):

I believe `multicore` spins off a separate process for each subtask.  If that assumption is correct, then you should be able to use `Sys.getpid()` to "seed" tempfile:

```
tempfile(pattern=paste("foo", Sys.getpid(), sep=""))
```

Comment: This is fine if I call tempfile in my own code, but what if I call, say embedFonts, which calls tempfile without the PID?

Comment: Good question.  `tempfile` calls `tempdir`, which consults the environment variables `TMPDIR`, `TMP`, and `TEMP`, in that order.  So maybe you can `Sys.setenv(TMPDIR=...)`

Comment: Setting environment variables didn't work. `tempdir` did not seem to respond to those changes. I chose to monkey-patch your suggested code into `tempfile` -- I updated the original question with that code.

Comment: Current documentation explains why setting those variables doesn't work:
"Note that setting any of these environment variables in the R session has no effect on tempdir(): the per-session temporary directory is created before the interpreter is started."

Answer (score 1):

Use the `x` in your function:

```
mclapply(1:4, function(x) tempfile(pattern=paste("file",x,"-",sep=""))
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the parallel jobs all run at the same time, and because the random seed comes from the system time, running four instances of tempfile in parallel will typically produce the same results (if you have 4 cores, that is.  If you only have two cores, you'll get two pairs of identical temp file names).

Better to generate the tempfile names first and give them to your function as an argument:

```
filenames <- tempfile( rep("file",4) )
mclapply( filenames, function(x){})
```

If you're using someone else's function that has a tempfile call in it, then working the PID into the tempfile name by modifying the tempfile function, as previously suggested, is probably the simplest plan:

```
tempfile <- function( pattern = "file", tmpdir = tempdir(), fileext = ""){
   .Internal(tempfile(paste("pid", Sys.getpid(), pattern, sep=""), tmpdir, fileext))}
mclapply( 1:4, function(x) tempfile() )
```